# How to remap key in keyboard on different layouts

Tags: xfce, keyboard-layout, mx-linux

I am using MX Linux with XFCE Desktop. For some reason, button right from the <kbd>.</kbd> key doesn't seem to work properly. It types `/` on English layout, but it doesn't type `.` and `,` on Russian layout (without <kbd>Shift</kbd> and with <kbd>Shift</kbd> respectively).

How can I change behavior of that key on Russian layout?

Comment: If your looking for a command line way of doing it you should check out [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24916/how-do-i-remap-certain-keys-or-devices) and questions tagged with [tag:xkb].

Comment: @LoïcReynier, I know, that I need to execute something like this
   `code` xmodmap -e 'keycode 61 = . `code`
but I don't know, how to set this behavior only on Russian layout. Your link didn't give me the answer...